# Flex Module Development Workflow

Tags: apache-flex, workflow, module

I have just started looking into using Modules in Flex and would like to know how you all go about developing them.  I understand how to use them (load, unload, application domains, shared classes, etc.), but I'm wondering what a good workflow is in creating them and using them in multiple applications.

If I were building reusable application components (text editor, image cropper, compass, whatever), and I wanted to reuse them in many different applications, it seems like I would:

1) Create an Application specifically for one of those modules
2) Create a Module inside that Application
3) Develop the Module by itself, make it work right
4) Link shared libraries to it somehow (like library projects I would use between all of the modules)
5) ... then I'm unclear what's next.  I now have lets say 10 Module/Applications, and I want to start mashing them together into usable applications.  What's the best way to do this?  I would like to not have to copy-paste code and swfs, using something like git submodules if an equivalent is possible.

Thanks so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [SWC files](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=building_overview_5.html).